# Need to block adult content from my phone

Tags: dns, privacy

Im trying to block all adult content from my phone. I tried changing private dns to family.adguard-dns.com. But its not blocking adult content from private browsers like tor. Which private dns hostname is best for blocking adult content from all private browsers? Please answer in simple terms so I can understand

I tried changing private hostname to above said name. But its not block adult content from tor browser and other private browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't block Tor by blocking DNS. That's part of the point of using Tor; all of its traffic goes over the Tor connection, including DNS lookups, as otherwise the lookups would reveal sites you were visiting to anyone monitoring your DNS. The public DNS requests actually occur on the Tor exit node, not on your browser. Tor is intentionally hard to block!